# Find the maximal interval of existence of IVP without a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem

Given the following Cauchy problem

$$ \begin{cases} x'=x^m(x-1)^n(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\ x(t_0)=x_0 \end{cases} $$

Where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. For every $(t_0, x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ Find the Maximal Interval of Existence.

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for $x(t)$, which makes me think I should use some other property of $x'$. I am aware that differentiating $x'$ will give me a way to find the interval where it's a locally lipschitz function, but I am not sure if this interval is the same as the Maximal Interval of Existence.

Comment: The RHS is not defined everyewhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wait, how is $x^m(x-1)^n(x-2)^{1/3}$ not defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$? The derivative of that expression isn't, but the expression itself is, or am I missing something?

Comment: $(0.5-2)^\frac{1}{3}$ lives in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ for example